# AmCharts4: Changing color of label line in PieChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

It's pretty straightforward: I need to change this lines color to white, but can't find the property that controls this line. Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
this.series.ticks.template.stroke=am4core.color("#ffffff");
```